# How to fix the Error Code 3780 MySQL in my code?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Hey I was trying to make a new databank but got the error code 3780. Do you have ideas how to fix it?
It says "referencing column 'fk_mitarbeiter' and referenced column 'Betriebsmail' in foreign key constraint 'Bestellung_ibfk_2' are incompatible"

```
CREATE TABLE Kunden (
Vorname varchar(30) not null,
Nachname varchar(50) not null,
Strasse varchar(30) not null,
Hausnummer int unsigned not null,
PLZ int unsigned not null,
Ort varchar(30) not null,
Mail varchar(50) not null,
Telefonnr int unsigned not null,
Kundennr int primary key auto_increment not null);

CREATE TABLE Bestellung (
Bestellnr int primary key auto_increment not null);

CREATE TABLE Produkt (
Produktname varchar(30) not null,
Preis int not null,
Produkt_ID int primary key auto_increment not null); 

CREATE TABLE Lieferant (
Firmenname varchar(30) not null,
Vorname varchar(30) not null,
Nachname varchar(30) not null,
Telefonnr int unsigned not null,
PRIMARY KEY (Firmenname, Vorname, Nachname)
);

CREATE TABLE Mitarbeiter (
Vorname varchar(30) not null,
Nachname varchar(30) not null,
Strasse varchar(30) not null,
Hausnr int unsigned not null,
PLZ int unsigned not null,
Ort varchar(30) not null,
Betriebsmail varchar(50) primary key not null);

ALTER TABLE Bestellung ADD COLUMN fk_kunden int;
ALTER TABLE Bestellung ADD FOREIGN KEY (fk_kunden) REFERENCES Kunden(Kundennr);

ALTER TABLE Bestellung ADD COLUMN fk_mitarbeiter int;
ALTER TABLE Bestellung ADD FOREIGN KEY (fk_mitarbeiter) REFERENCES Mitarbeiter(Betriebsmail);

ALTER TABLE Produkt ADD COLUMN fk_bestellung int;
ALTER TABLE Produkt ADD FOREIGN KEY (fk_bestellung) REFERENCES Bestellung(Bestellnr);

ALTER TABLE Produkt ADD COLUMN fk_lieferant int;
ALTER TABLE Produkt ADD FOREIGN KEY (fk_lieferant) REFERENCES Lieferant(Firmenname, Vorname, Nachname);
```

Thank you in advance

i was trying to reference tables together but it gave me this error

Comment: ALTER TABLE Bestellung ADD COLUMN fk_mitarbeiter int; but then you try to reference Mitarbeiter(Betriebsmail) varchar something.

Comment: omg thank you so much. I dont know how i didnt see that